# Nested movieclip rotation doesn't work if parent rotates too

Tags: actionscript-3, rotation, nested, parent, encapsulation

I have a tank which has a nested movieclip called Barrel.

Barrel successfully faces the player, unless the tank itself rotates.

So it only works if the tank doesn't rotate.

I need to find a way to make the rotation work, and I googled and found:

```
var rot:Number = rotation, p:DisplayObjectContainer = parent, s:DisplayObjectContainer =     stage;
while (p != s) {
  rot += p.rotation;
  p = p.parent;
}
```

But I have no idea how to implement this in my current code:

```
// calculate rotation based on target

            _dx = this.x - _root.hero.x;
            _dy = this.y - _root.hero.y;

// which way to rotate

            _rotateTo = getDegrees(getRadians(_dx, _dy));   

// keep rotation positive, between 0 and 360 degrees

            if (_rotateTo > barrel.rotation + 90) _rotateTo -= 360;
            if (_rotateTo < barrel.rotation - 90) _rotateTo += 360;

// ease rotation

            _trueRotation = (_rotateTo - barrel.rotation) /     _rotateSpeedMax;

//barrel rotation

            barrel.rotation += _trueRotation;
```

I tried changing

```
barrel.rotation += _trueRotation;
```

to

```
barrel.rotation += _trueRotation + parent.rotation
```

after reading online that you can simply add all the rotations, but it doesn't seem to work.

How can I implement

```
var rot:Number = rotation, p:DisplayObjectContainer = parent, s:DisplayObjectContainer =         stage;
while (p != s) {
  rot += p.rotation;
  p = p.parent;
}
```

into my code?

Answer (score 0):

You have to negate the rotation of parent(s), thus you just change `+=` to `-=`, should do.

```
 rot -= p.rotation;
```

Comment: But I don't know where in the code to use the whole rot -= p.rotation thingy. Where in my code should I place all of that code? (from "var rot:number" to "p = p.parent", the 5 line code at the start and end

Comment: You need to make a function for your `barrel` that will make it rotate towards the player, calculate barrel's rotation then adjust it via given code.

Comment: So I just put all of the last code in an ENTER_FRAME class for the barrel, right?

Comment: Yes I think, since you need to calculate the rotation each frame.

Comment: Is there any way you could give me an example of some sort? I have tried fiddling around with the code but no matter what I do, either the rotation still doesn't work or it goes crazy, rotating in all directions